# Rails: How to generate a random order of "next post" in rails unique to each user?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model where a user can enter a multiple choice question. I have a view where a user can click "previous" or "next", and it takes them up 1 or down 1 in the database.

However, I want to make it so that..

A. User clicks on "next", is taken to a new random question **that hasn't been viewed before.**

B. User clicks on "prev", is taken to the **last question that was done**, and the last question done before that.

C. User should have different order of "next" as compared to other users.

How can I go about doing this?

**post.rb**

```
def next
    Post.where("id > ?", id).order(id: :asc).limit(1).first
end

def prev
     Post.where("id < ?", id).order(id: :desc).limit(1).first
end
```

posts_controller.rb

```
def show 
@post = Post.friendly.find(params[:id])


# this is used in the show.html.erb view for posts
@randomize_posts = [
  @post.answer_choice,
  @post.answer_choice_2,
  @post.answer_choice_3,
  @post.answer_choice_4,
  @post.answer_choice_5
].shuffle

end
```

posts/show.html.erb

```
<%= link_to "← Previous Question", @post.prev, :class => 'button previous-question' %>

<%= link_to "Next Question →", @post.next, :class => 'button next-question' %>
```

Comment: "I have a model where a user can enter a multiple choice question" -- Do you mean you have a **view**?

Comment: Yes @sawa, sorry that's what i meant.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few ways of doing this. I'd recommend doing a deterministic approach where different users get different results, but the same user will always have the same result. This allows for you to have randomness and do forward/backward navigation without storing extra data.

To randomize on a deterministic way, you can apply an `md5` method on the post's id and the current user id:

```
posts = Post.order("md5('#{current_user.id}' || posts.id::text)")
```

Now the simplest way of finding the next and the previous is to see which one is right after and before the current one. You know the current one's position by calculating its `md5` hash, so you just need to find which one comes right after or right before:

```
Post
  .where("md5('?' || '?') > md5('?' || posts.id::text)", current_user.id, id, current_user.id)
  .order("md5('#{current_user.id}' || posts.id::text)")
  .limit(1)
```

Applying to your model, it could look something like:

```
def next(user)
   ordered_posts(user)
     .where("md5('?' || '?') > md5('?' || posts.id::text)", user.id, id, user.id)
end

def prev(user)
  ordered_posts(user)
     .where("md5('?' || '?') < md5('?' || posts.id::text)", user.id, id, user.id)
end

private

def ordered_posts(user)
  Post.order("md5('#{current_user.id}' || posts.id::text)")
end
```

And the view would look like:

```
<%= link_to "← Previous Question", @post.prev(current_user), :class => 'button previous-question' %>

<%= link_to "Next Question →", @post.next(current_user), :class => 'button next-question' %>
```

Comment: When I add the post.order method in the posts controller like this: `@post = Post.friendly.find(params[:id]).order("md5('#{current_user.id}' || posts.id::text)")` I get an error: undefined method `order'

Comment: You can't order after a `find`. When you use the `find` method you know exactly which one you want to find (you're giving the id), so ordering doesn't make sense in that case.

Comment: I didn't know that, that's very helpful! Thank you. However, now that I've added your implementation of the model, I get an error: `wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1)` on the def prev(user) line

Comment: In your view, you have to call the methods passing the `current_user`. I've updated the answer to show how the view would look like

Comment: Oh duh. Can't believe I missed that. But now I'm getting a `undefined local variable or method current_use` error? Thanks for your help. Not sure why Rails isn't cooperating

Comment: I assumed you were using "devise" which automatically fills up the variable `current_user` for a signed in user, but I didn't have that detail from the question. `current_user` is whichever `User` is signed in and seeing the post.